# Performing filtering and sorting on the original collection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, filtering

I have got stucked in a scenario that i have a custom collection class which inherits form ICollection interface and i have a code segement like following:

```
myCustomCollectionObject.Where(obj=>obj.isValid).ToList().Sort(mycustomerComparer);
```

above code filters the original collection and then sort the collection
now in this kind of scenario sorting would be performed on a different collection rather than original collection.

**So, is there any way or workaround for implementing first filtering then sorting on the original collection**

Comment: What type is `myCustomCollectionObject`?

Comment: Why would you want to filter, and *then* sort? Why can't you sort the original collection, then filter?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the type is UndoRedoObseravableCollection : ICollection
{
}

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: Are you sure? Calling a class `OberservableCollection` without implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` seems pretty strange.

Comment: @RowlandShaw i want to filter because the collection has some emtpy or invalid rows due to some business logic we got 2000 static rows that may be empty and other business logics

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes that implements the same, do you want to me give full screeenshot of the class

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: *All* interfaces and base classes would be enough for the beginning, I guess.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth here is the class template

Class UndoRedoObservableCollection<T> : ICollection<T>,INotifyPropertyChanged,IUndoRedoMember,INotifyCollectionChange
{

Comment: How do you store the elements of your collection? Something like `private List<T>`?

Comment: @YogeshJoshi what's wrong with `OrderBy` and then reassigning?

Comment: @nawfal i have stored some changeset information in the collection if i reassign ,then that changeset information would be lost actually, it is a collection in Dejavu(UndoRedo open source library)

Comment: @YogeshJoshi you anyway want your initial collection to be modified (ie, re-ordered). So now why not do `OrderBy` and reassign? Or do you mean you need to re-order by ignoring some items in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the immutable/functional goodness of Linq, then you have to go old-skool:

```
//Remove unwanted items
for (int i = myCustomCollectionObject.Length; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    if(!myCustomCollectionObject[i].IsValid)
        myCustomCollectionObject.Remove(myCustomCollectionObject[i]);
}

myCustomCollectionObject.Sort(mycustomerComparer);
```

Comment: The collection implements `ICollection`, but not `IList`, so it may not support indexing.

Comment: Yeah - good point. If that's the case - then you probably can't do anything to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to learn `myCustomCollectionObject` isn't `List<T>`, hence a complete rewrite.

---

**Approach 1:**

Have a `Sort` method in your class

```
List<T> backingStructure; //assuming this is what you have.

public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    backingStructure = backingStructure.Where(obj => obj.isValid).ToList();
    backingStructure.Sort(comparer);
}
```

and call `Sort` on the internal backing structure. I assume it has to be `List<T>` or `Array` both which has `Sort` on them. I have added the filtering logic internal to your 
`Sort` method.

**Approach 2:**

If you don't want that, ie you want your filtering logic to be external to class, then have a method to repopulate your backing structure from an `IEnumerable<T>`. Like:

```
List<T> backingStructure; //assuming this is what you have.

//return type chosen to make method name meaningful, up to you to have void
public UndoRedoObservableCollection<T> From(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    backingStructure.Clear();
    foreach(var item in list)
        //populate and return;
}
```

Call it like

```
myCustomCollectionObject = myCustomCollectionObject.From
                           (
                               myCustomCollectionObject.Where(obj => obj.isValid)
                                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                           );
```

But you will need a key to specify ordering.

**Approach 3 (the best of all):**

Have a `RemoveInvalid` method

```
List<T> backingStructure; //assuming this is what you have.

public void RemoveInvalid()
{
    //you can go for non-Linq (for loop) removal approach as well.
    backingStructure = backingStructure.Where(obj => obj.isValid).ToList();
}

public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    backingStructure.Sort(comparer);
}
```

Call it:

```
myCustomCollectionObject.RemoveInvalid();    
myCustomCollectionObject.Sort(mycustomerComparer);
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question, this is not what i want

Comment: @YogeshJoshi sorry about that. But how much more can I make out from merely *So, is there any way or workaround for implementing first filtering then sorting on the original collection* in the question? Please update your question with some samples/examples. But more than anything, I am now curious to know what exactly your requirement is since I cant think of another possibility :)

Comment: @svick too hard on me, isn't it? I will have to glean thru the entire comments to pick that. Nevertheless I will update my code.

Comment: @nawfal It's mentioned in the first sentence of the question: “i have a custom collection class”.

Comment: @svick indeed, thanks and apologies. Was quick to jump to code block and find `Sort`, `ToList` etc and all what followed made it look like the issue is *that he can't sort on the original list* rather than emphasize on custom collection thing :)